# Java - while loop adding first output to second output

Tags: java, loops, methods

I have a program that takes any roman value as a user input and outputs the decimal equivalent. I am trying to add a loop to the program to ask indefinitely for a roman value then output the decimal equivalent, then loop back and ask again....

Comment: and you want to print `1000` ?

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to initialize ```decimalNum``` before you start with the next number?

Comment: Yeah, roman value of M = 1000 (decimal), first output was I = 1, so program somehow is taking first value output (1) and adding it to second meaning M = 1001. And of course the program is doing this for all further values, meaning only first value entered is correct

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `decimalNum` is a global variable that should (but is not) re-initialized inside the while loop after the user enters a roman number.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset `decimalNum` for every conversion.

```
while (true) {
        decimalNum = 0;
.....
```

The Problem is after calculating decimal for `I` the value is stored in variable `decimalNum`. When you are starting conversion for next one it is adding the new value to existing one.

Answer (score 0):

As you have got `decimalNum` as `static` (at class level), the same variable is being used over multiple iterations, so move it to the inside `while` loop  as `int decimalNum =0;`